# importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: regex while building an .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to build an executable with pyinstaller and I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transformers/utils/versions.py", line 105, in require_version
  File "importlib/metadata.py", line 551, in version
  File "importlib/metadata.py", line 524, in distribution
  File "importlib/metadata.py", line 187, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: regex

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chatbot2.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "transformers/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "transformers/dependency_versions_check.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "transformers/utils/versions.py", line 120, in require_version_core
  File "transformers/utils/versions.py", line 107, in require_version
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: The 'regex!=2019.12.17' distribution was not found and is required by this application. 
Try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git master
[30391] Failed to execute script 'chatbot2' due to unhandled exception!
```

I am using PyInstaller version 5.0.dev0 and Python version 3.9.1.

I tried pip3.9 install transformers, pip3.9 install regex, I tried adding hooks hook-regex.py and hook-transformers.py.
I would really appreciate any suggestions! Thank you!

Comment: I asked this question on the pyinstaller Github page and I received an answer that helped me solve these errors. I'm leaving the link here for anyone encountering the same errors: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6033#discussioncomment-1019235